# convergence of series involving powers

Tags: real-analysis

Test the following series for convergence:

a. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n}{(n)^{n+\frac{5}{4}}}$$

b. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

When I tried using ratio and root tests for (a), the limit came out to be $1$. So I could reach no conclusion.

May be limit comparison test can be used . Not sure which series to compare it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first series, write

$$\frac{(n + 1)^n}{n^{n + 5/4}} = \left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)^n \frac{1}{n^{5/4}} \le \frac{3}{n^{5/4}}$$

since $(1 + 1/n)^n \to e$, for large enough $n$.

---

As a hint for the second, show that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \tan \frac 1 x = 1$$

Use this to apply the comparison test.